# NSTimer change image iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

How to change images periodically using NSTimer in iPhone progranmming?

I create an image view for loading images.

I want to display images in imageview and periodically change images by using NSTimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the images you like to your bundle application
called them image1.png, image2.png image3.png and so on....

Add UIImageview in interface builder call it (reference) "theImage"

in the H file:

```
@interface delme3ViewController : UIViewController {

    UIImageView *theImage;
    int imageCount;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImage;

@end
```

in the M file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(animateFunction) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
    imageCount = 1;

}

-(void)animateFunction
{
    NSLog(@"Timer heartbeat %i",imageCount);
    imageCount = imageCount + 1;
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png"];
    [theImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using NSTimer, I would just use an arrary of UIImages and animate them.  See the documentation [from here](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html).

Comment: The result of this method is WAY smoother animation with many large images.

Comment: How would i fade in and out images using this? Make the time intervals a little longer but also which method calls a fadeinandout/alpha change to a uiimageview?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use array of image names rather renaming images in your bundle. :)

Comment: Or one can use an array of UIImage objects.  (Though because of the way the system caches images this won't generally provide any benefits.)