# Continuously Updating Image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to continuously update an image on one of my view controllers. The image is from [this image URL](http://fxp7.sensr.net/latest/e234d1fbd98a6505149d834ba6fd1810a82c0d9b) that is continuously getting updated. If you keep refreshing that URL you can see the image changing. I'm effectively trying to get this to happen in my app.

I've tried loops but the loops freeze the view until it is completed. I'd like it to refresh the image every X seconds.

Right now I can refresh the image using a button:

```
@IBAction func refreshDogAction(sender:AnyObject) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://fxp7.sensr.net/latest/e234d1fbd98a6505149d834ba6fd1810a82c0d9b")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    dogImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

I'd like to have this happen automatically without having to click the button.

Comment: you can use a timer and pass a function that gets called every x seconds, which will update the image. Heres an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686642/nstimer-change-image-iphone-programming

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using NStimer say somthing like this for every 2 seconds.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("loadImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func loadImage(){
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://fxp7.sensr.net/latest/e234d1fbd98a6505149d834ba6fd1810a82c0d9b")
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
            dogImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

Comment: selector: "loadImage"

Comment: sorry yeah case typo